# How to validate in Laravel id_room is not available when books table has 1 id room at same day

Tags: php, laravel

I'm stuck in validating id_room when  books table has 1 id room at same day.

i use this because the hotel has 2 recepsionist

```
        $request->validate([
            'id_room' => ['required', 'integer', Rule::unique('books')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                return
                    $startDate = date('Y-m-d');
                $hotelId =
                    Auth::user()->id_hotel;
                $query->where('id_room', $request->id_room)->whereDate('book_date', $startDate)->where('id_hotel', $hotelId);
            })],
            'guestname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'nik' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'nota' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'price' => ['required', 'integer'],
        ]);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you explain your problem more ?

Comment: @xenooooo well, I have validated the available room at view, but when there are 2 receptionists making reservations at once,so the room available at view is still available, even though a few seconds ago one of the receptionists made a reservation, so I need to laravel validation to avoid duplicate id room at same day, do u get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your current query is fine. It's just the return is $startDate.

Try to return the query instead and change how you use whereDate

```
'id_room' => ['required', 'integer', Rule::unique('books')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($request) 
    {
      return $query
        ->where('id_room', $request->id_room)
        ->whereDate('book_date', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->where('id_hotel', auth()->user()->id_hotel);
    })
],
```

*extra note based on your comments:*
related to book_date and keeping 2 receptionists not able to book the same id_room, i think this validation only is not enough.
best to add extra check down the code just before insert transaction
and use DB transaction to revert back when same id_room was already been booked on same check-in and check-out date (or in between)

Comment: are you sure the validation won't work when the book date has been completed?
I'm afraid the unique check still works even though the day has changed

Comment: the ledger date ? can you please clarify ? btw bs bahasa, bang? ledger == books table ?

Comment: so what do you mean by book_date has been completed ? the booking day has passed? this validation will check the table in real time, correct ? perhaps you need to improve the query so a double booking on the same room_id should not happen. add check on book_status, room_id but already check_out, etc